# React native application sticks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

how are you?

I turn to you for a little wisdom friends.

I tell you, I have an application made with react native only for an android tablet, the application is super good, but sometimes, when we leave it open with the screen on for a while, (20 minutes or more) and then we want to make a form, the app raises a modal notifying that the action is being done, and activates an activity indicator in the modal, all good up to there, only that it never progresses from there, not until we close the app and launch it again, We repeat the form and it is sent without problems, this issue only occurs in release mode and it has been almost impossible for us to discover what causes this behavior, do you have any idea what it might be?

Any help would be a lot! Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 0):

What i can predict is that the data inside modal is losing the state after this much delay. Maybe you can connect the tablet with pc and run android studio to see the logs

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for your comment, I just have a question, in release mode can I see the logs of the application?